# replace strings no matter lowercase or uppercase using sed command

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I use the following command to replace strings in texts:

```
    grep -rl "abc" A.txt | xargs sed -i 's/abc/efg/g'.
```

But I also want to replace `Abc` with `efg`. The following command seems not working.

```
    grep -irl "abc" A.txt | xargs sed -i 's/abc/efg/g'
```

using the `-i` for grep is to find case-insensitive lines, but in the subsequent `sed` command, it will won't admit `Abc`.

So, my question is how to `sed` to replace case-insensitive texts?

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} {gsub(/abc/,"efg")}1' A.txt > a.tmp && mv a.tmp A.txt
```

Example:

```
 echo -e "abc\nABC\nhey abc" |awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1} {gsub(/abc/,"efg")}1'
efg
efg
hey efg
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer! In my case, there are many strings to be replaced. I think this method might generate many temporary files. For example, I need to execute a lot of commands like this: `find . -name "*.tex" | xargs grep -irl "tu2015futher" | xargs sed -i 's/tu2015futher/tu\_futher\_2015/g'`. And there are many `tu2015futher`-like strings to be replaces to other corresponding strings.

Answer (score 0):

Capitalize the 'I'.

```
grep -irl "abc" do.py | xargs sed -i 's/abc/efg/gI'
```

Or, use another regex like this

```
grep -irl "abc" do.py | xargs sed -i 's/[Aa]bc/efg/g'
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer! In the post, I use `abc` and `efg` for example. In my case, there are many other strings, thus, this method might be not efficient.